# Error using strftime on hour in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, strftime

In My index I have @date.day, and when I use @date.strftime("%B %Y"), it works just fine.

But a litle further in the code, I have aula.time2. 
It gives me smt like "2000-01-01 10:00:00 UTC" which is ugly.
But if I try to print aula.time2.strftime("%I %M") It wont work.

It gives me this Error:
undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

Any Ideas?

Index:

```
    <div id="articles">
      <h2 id="month">
        <%= link_to "<", date: @date.prev_week %>

        <%= @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>

        <%= link_to ">", date: @date.next_week%>
      </h2>
        <%= calendar @date do |date| %>

        <%= date.day %>

        <% if @aulas_by_date[date] %>
          <ul>          
            <% @aulas_by_date[date].each do |aula| %>
             <%= aula.time2.strftime("%I %M") %>

    </div>

            <% end %>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: You sure all the aulas are not-nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be that the "Aulas" were all nill.
Thanks Dave Newton